# Custom Data Type Renderer deployment

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

How should I export Custom Data Type Renderer that is made to be used as expression in the Debugger for particular type?  Should I export it as plugin jar or just jar that will only contain the classes to be referenced in Android Studio directory?

I have built it with Idea SDK and as plugin module but I'm not using any of the packages so far, rather than JDK packages. I tried exporting it as plugin and installing it from disk, however I can't use the classes in the expressions. This is not documented in the open idea sdk documentation anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the module as Java application module. `Main` class was left empty. Exported the artifact and moved the jar in Android SDK path, precisely at `\sdk\sources\android-23\java`. Now I can see the classes in completion in expression text field:

`[image: shot]